# I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with this query..?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO partners(location_id)
SELECT
   location.id
FROM
   location
JOIN partners
   ON location.city = partners.City
```

It runs the query but it doesn't insert any values into the location_id field in the partners table.

Comment: How about the SQL error ?

Comment: Do you really have table "partners" with one column "location_id" only? When inserting you usually have to add more columns

Comment: I don't get an error, that's whats so frustrating. It says it executes on the 38k records, but all I'm left with is 0 values in the int field "location_id"

Comment: Does `partners` contain the cities that `location` have?

Comment: I see some Uppercase `City` and lowercase `city`, could that be something ?

Comment: is location_id field marked as auto increment?

Comment: Also what's the output of `SELECT location.id FROM location Join ...` ? could help out to see what's getting inserted

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Yes if I just run the SELECT portion it comes up with exactly what I'd like to insert. I'm normalizing the partners table city/location information and trying to reference the location table id's back into partners... I have no idea why its giving me all 0's after the query.

Comment: Can you show me the schema of the partners table ?

Comment: What happens if you do the insert into a NEW table? (IE Not 'partners')? Im wondering about selecting / inserting into the same space.

Comment: Does any of the columns in `partners` table have `index` or `NOT NULL` on them?

Comment: from what you are dong, it seems you actually want to run an UPDATE query to update the partners table by adding LocationID if City is there if so, then run update partners set location_id= (select location_id from location where location.city=partners.City limit 1) or something similar.

Comment: @SumitGupta ...incredible... its so obvious I want to tear my brain out. This is what happens when you've been up for 20+ hours (and you suck at SQL)

Comment: I work 16hrs daily, and you know SQL, just that you get confuse in what need to be done. It happens with tired brain.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that the query in question is case sensitive?

If so, you have location.city = partners.City

City or city may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using aliases:

```
INSERT INTO partners(location_id)
SELECT
   location.id
FROM
   location l
JOIN partners p
   ON l.city = p.City
```

Two tables with same name would confuse me if I was SQL interpretator..